# Upload to amazon s3 error "EntityTooLarge" for 20 megabyte file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3

i am trying to upload a file directly to amazon s3, however after the upload completes i get the following error:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
    <Code>EntityTooLarge</Code>
<Message>
    Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size
</Message>
<ProposedSize>5245254</ProposedSize>
<RequestId>645D7BA0DCC454D9</RequestId>
<HostId>
    9ZX65MGwKi/hpe05eJuNp6mPgsRPZk54bplqX93ImjlLzojSesXCGRCZRjrkUDK8
</HostId>
    <MaxSizeAllowed>5242880</MaxSizeAllowed>
</Error>
```

**There seems to be a limit of 5242880 bytes for MaxSizeAllowed how can i change this limit from amazon's side. thanks for the help**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this same problem using the carrierwave_direct gem and found this line in the documentation (placed in the carrierwave.rb initializer):

```
config.max_file_size     = 10.megabytes        # defaults to 5.megabytes
```

By changing the default I was able to upload a larger file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using SOAP interface for file uploads.

Try to use REST interface instead:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectPUT.html

for files larger than 5 GB you need to use Multipart upload:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadInitiate.html

Comment: thanks for the info, i have borrowed most of the code from the d2s3 plugin https://github.com/mwilliams/d2s3/tree/master/lib/d2s3, so how to change to rest is a bit foreign to me. What would i need to change specific to the d2s3 code to achieve a REST interface?